# Always On AvailabiltyGroup SSRS Report Example

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to create an SSRS report for looking at issues I am having with AG, does anyone have examples they may have seen or done, I have looked in as many places as I can think of, but there do not seem to be any,

Comment: This may help --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/monitor-availability-groups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: please add a piece of code with this reference on what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for this, have looked through and there are a number of things I can use, one thing that seems to be missing is being able to see the Health log, again, doing some digging, many ppl have suggested that this cannoit be done because of the way this is created, anybody got any other thoughts on this.  I have seen and tried some code that goes some of the way, and have looked at the extended event for this, but don't seem to be able to get all of what I could really do with.